# What causes SVN "Working copy <path> is locked"?

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoise-svn

I wrote a console application that uses SharpSVN to update 3 folders in my repository. Wanted to convert that to a batch script to removed the dependency on SharpSVN.

Came up with this:

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Core" /closeonend:0
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Modules" /closeonend:0
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\MW" /closeonend:0
```

I found [this as an answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943508/1189566). When I run it, I get 3 windows pop up from Tortoise.

One says:

`Error: Working copy 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC' locked.

Error: 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC' is already locked.`

A second one says:

`Error: Working copy 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager' locked.

Error: 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC' is already locked.`

And the third one successfully updates the Modules folder. Anyone know what's causing the first two to be locked?

Comment: I've seen this happen for no apparent reason.  I don't know what causes it, but, an svn "clean" of the folder will usually fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer to my issue. Basically, Tortoise puts a lock on a folder any time it tries to do something. My script was just immediately launching 3 updaters, without waiting for the previous one to finish.

The `START` command has a `/wait` flag that waits for whatever it runs to exit, so I modified my script as follows:

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START /wait TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Core" /closeonend:1
START /wait TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Modules" /closeonend:1
START /wait TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\MW" /closeonend:1
```

Unfortunately, I have to close the update window that Tortoise opens in order for the script to be fully automated. This means that I can't observe what files were modified or added.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN when used manually can update multiple directories with a single command, simply by selecting multiple folders before running the Update command. The command-line `svn update` also accepts multiple targets. So, I'd fully expect the TortoiseSVN command-line should also accept multiple paths. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html shows an example for *committing* multiple files, does that syntax also work for updating? I don't have TortoiseSVN on the computer I'm on at the moment.